# Why mysql is saying column is unknown?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two tables student and my view having some tuples
i have been trying to learn joins all other types of joins worked well but with full outer join why its saying column is undefined

Student table

[image]

Myview table

[image]

SQL query

```sql
select * from student
full join myview
on
student.id = myview.id;
```

Error

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'student.id' in 'on clause'

I need to get joined records

Comment: ??? MySQL does not implement FULL JOIN. [MySQL: JOIN clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). You must emulate it.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try following?

```
SELECT * FROM student FULL OUTER JOIN myView ON student.id = myView.id;
```

For mySQL try following. (mySQL doesn't provide full join.)

```
SELECT * FROM student 
LEFT JOIN myView ON student.id = myView.id 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM student 
RIGHT JOIN myView ON student.id = myView.id
```

Comment: I tried then it suggested to remove outer keyword and then giving the same error as before

Comment: @siddharthsingh which SQL RDBMS are you using? mySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: @AbhishekKolge Error message claims that OP uses MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: @AbhishekKolge its mysql

Comment: @siddharthsingh mysql doesn't have full join. You can try some work around.

Comment: @AbhishekKolge yes there is cross join for the same pupose thanks dude